# Tile collision with sliding along walls

Tags: java, slide, collision, tile

[image: ...]

I've got a ball that I can move around on a map consisting of equally sized tiles. The player should not be able to walk over the tiles that are darker and have a black border. I've got a multidimensional array of the tiles that I use to check which tiles are solid.

I would like the player to slide against the wall if he is moving both horizontally and vertically into it. The problem is that if he does that he sticks to the wall. I managed to get it working perfectly on each axis, but separately. Here is my code for the horizontal collision checking:

```
if (vx < 0) {
    // checks for solid tiles left of the player
    if (level.isBlocked(i, j) || level.isBlocked(i, jj)) {
        x = side * (i + 1); // moves player to left side of tile
        vx = 0;
    }
} else if (vx > 0) {
    // checks for solid tiles right of the player
    if (level.isBlocked(ii, j) || level.isBlocked(ii, jj)) {
        x = (ii * side) - getWidth(); // moves player to right side of tile
        vx = 0;
    }
}
```

The *level.isBlocked()* method checks if that index of the array is occupied by a solid tile. The *i* and *j* variables is which index in the array the player's top right corner is located on. The *ii* and *jj* variables is which index in the array the player's bottom right corner is located on.

This works fine, but then if I add the same chunk of code beneath but replacing *x* with *y*, *vx* with *vy* and so on the problem occurs. So I can add either the horizontal or vertical collision handling and it works, but not at the same time. I've seen a few articles explaining I have to separate them or something, but I didn't understand much of them. How can I check collision on both axes and keep the sliding effect?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the problematic behavior) versus the desired behavior?  Looks like the player can move (with inertia) in any direction, and if the player moves toward top right corner and collides with a vertical wall you want the player to continue moving up but not right?  What happens now?

Comment: If I move left and keep moving after I hit the wall the horizontal code collision code will execute and stop me from going through the wall. If I then also move the player up it executes the horizontal and vertical collision code, which causes the player to snap to top left corner of tile beneath the one it is on.

What I would like it to do instead is slide against the wall so it moves up, just like you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Angelatlarge's answer was helpful in understanding the problem, but I decided to start from scratch. I ended up first calculating the new x and y position and storing them in separate variables. Then I checked the tile under the middle left of the player and the same with the middle right. I then set a boolean to true if the player was standing on a tile because of his horizontal speed. If there was no collision I set the real x variable to the new one I calculated earlier. I then repeated the same thing for the vertical collision.

This is for the horizontal checking:

```
float newX = x + vx * delta;
boolean xCollision = false;
if (vx < 0) {
    int i = level.toIndex(x);
    int j = level.toIndex(y + getHeight() / 2);
    xCollision = level.isBlocked(i, j);
} else if (vx > 0) {
    int i = level.toIndex(x + getWidth());
    int j = level.toIndex(y + getHeight() / 2);
    xCollision = level.isBlocked(i, j);
}
if (!xCollision) x = newX;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with the setup you have, given a block and the player position, and also given the fact that they overlap, you don't know whether the player collided with a vertical or a horizontal wall of the block.  So see this more clearly consider the following block and two collision paths
[image]

The top path will collide with the left wall, and requires a `vx=0;` (cessation of horizontal movement), while the bottom path collides with the bottom wall and will require  `vy=0;`, or stopping of the vertical movement.

I think in order to do the kind of collision detection you want, you will want to compute intersections of the player path and the **walls** of the blocks, not just checking whether the player overlaps a block. You could hack the desired behavior by computing the overlapping rectange of the player rectangle and the block rectangle. Consider the following situation:

[image]

where the red seqare represents your player. The fact that the overlap rectangle (the small rectangle occupied where the player is on top of the block) is more wide than it is tall *suggests* that it was the vertical collision that happened, not a horizontal. This is not foolproof, however. And it still requires you to be able to access the **shape** of the block, rather than just stesting if a part of the player rectangle overlaps a block.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work.